# List comprehension remove item

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to remove items using a list comprehension and the `remove()` method.

```
a = [1,2,2,2,3]
b = [2]
```

Expected output: `[1,3]`

I have tried the following but it returns a `None`:

```
new_list = [a.remove(number) for number in a if number in b]
```

Just to clarify I have solved the problems in other ways like the following:

```
    def array_diff(a, b):#solution 1
        new_list = [number for number in a if number not in b]
        return new_list
```

But I would like to use the `remove()` method just for fun.

Comment: `remove` is an in-place operation

Comment: `new_list = [number for number in a if number not in b]` is a better approach

Answer (score 2):

`remove` doesn't return anything. So `[a.remove(something) for ...]` is always going to be `[None, None, None...]`

Since it is an in-place modification, you can't use it like this. Something like this would work

```
for num in b:
  while b in a:
    a.remove(b)
return a
```

But, this is a really bad way to approach this as you wind up iterating over the list a whole bunch of times, while your list comprehension example iterates once. If you want to get a bit better, your list comprehension DOES iterate over `b` a bunch of times- if `b` could be large, you'd want to do...

```
to_remove = set(b)
return [num for num in a if num not in to_remove]
```

since the `in` operation on a set is constant time.

Comment: To avoid searching twice with `b in a` and `a.remove(b)` you could use `try/except` to detect when all elements are removed.

Comment: Good idea, will cut the number of searches in half (though we're still in exponential time)

Comment: He's just doing this "for fun", presumably just to learn more about how `delete()` works. Efficiency is probably not a concern.

Comment: Which is why I answered at all- but if it's "for fun" I enjoy talking about efficient ways to do things :)

Comment: @Barmar: Except for the fact that you can't put a `try/except` in a list comprehension.

Comment: @martineau I was suggesting it as a replacemnt the `while b in a:` loop, not the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```py
a = [1,2,2,2,3]
b = [2]

[a.remove(i) for i in a[:] if i in b] # iterate over a shallow copy

print(a)

>[1, 3]
```

Comment: A list comprehension whose result is ignored is basically just a `for` loop and should be written that way.

Comment: @Barmar isn't a list comprehension faster than a `for loop`? however there is no need to even have any variable, simply do: `[a.remove(i) for i in a[:] if i in b] # iterate over a shallow copy`

Comment: A list comprehension may be faster than a for loop that calls `append()` to create the result list. But in this case you don't need to create a result list.